# What is the way to add Parse objects into a NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I have a mutable array named "eventnameArray". What i want is to add objects. This objects to add come from a Parse query.

This is the mutable array:

```
eventArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

This is the Parse query, which works.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];
[query selectKeys:@[@"EventName"]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu scores.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects


       [eventnameArray addObject:[objects valueForKey:@"EventName"]];



        NSLog(@"%@", eventnameArray);

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

I suspect the problem is in the addObject call, which is not being performed correctly, or maybe in the whole PFQuery structure.

To show the array in the tableviewcell, i do this:

```
cell.label.text = [self.eventnameArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
```

EDIT :

I replaced addObject for addObjectsFromArray like this:

```
[eventnameArray addObjectsFromArray:[objects valueForKey:@"EventName"]];
```

But i still can't get it to work.

EDIT 2:

I replaced EDIT 1 with :

```
for (NSObject *object in objects){
            NSString *name = [object valueForKey:@"EventName"];
            [eventnameArray addObject:name];
        }
```

But the label still doesn't show anything.

EDIT 3 :

The solution was just a matter or reloading data like this:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: What does this `[objects valueForKey:@"EventName"]`  return?

Comment: It returns an Array of the actual String values of the EventName parse column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to add the `EventName` of each object in the `objects` array to your `eventnameArray`, not the "EventName" value of the `objects` array.
Try this instead:

```
for (NSObject *object in objects){
    NSString *name = [object valueForKey:@"EventName"];
    [eventnameArray addObject:name];
}
//EDIT: Addition for a complete fix. Reload the tabeview afterwards.
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: You contributed a lot to the solution ! Thank you

Comment: Marking as an answer is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're looking for is to replace `addObject:` with `addObjectsFromArray:` because parse returns an array to you so calling `valueForKey:@"EventName"` will return an array and you want to add all of those names to your `eventArray`.

So:

```
[eventnameArray addObjectsFromArray:[objects valueForKey:@"EventName"]];
```

Comment: It seems that theres a problem inside the query because if i do a normal addobject with @"hello" for example to the array outside the PFQuery, the label shows "hello", so i don't know what can be happening

Comment: Do you mean that the table view isn't updated to display the new items in the array?

Comment: thats correct!. I tried Bensge's solution which makes total sense, but i still can't get the label to show anything.

Comment: So this is a separate problem to updating the array, you need to call `[self.tableView reloadData]` after you have updated the array... You should have seen the array log the correct contents with either my code or that from @Bensge

Comment: Finally that was the solution !